# failed to compile testmain package - compile, no such file

Tags: linux, go, asdf

I'm new to Go programming and trying to set up the BDD framework Godog. I have extracted the Linux binary from the Github releases page and placed it on my $PATH. When I run it, I get the following error:

```
Error: failed to compile testmain package: fork/exec /opt/hostedtoolcache/go/1.17.7/x64/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/compile: no such file or directory - output:
```

For some reason `godog version` does not show an actual version, which leads me to believe it's not installed correctly.

```
❯ godog version
Show current version
```

Additional system information:

```
❯ go version
go version go1.18.3 linux/amd64
```

I don't know if this is relevant, but I'm using asdf to manage my local go installation.

Comment: Learn std Go testing first before doing fancy stuff with uncommon tools.

Comment: go is a compiled language. If you download the binary, then the binary does not need go in your machine. You need to download the sources, if you want to compile it yourself.